# Matplotlib: How to plot an specfic curve without legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib

For example. I have two curves. One is the real curve and the other is just a dashed line to indicate an specific point:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x2=[0,0.5,0.5]
y2=[0.5,0.5,0]
plt.plot(x2,y2,ls='dashed')

x1=[0,1]
y1=[0,1]
plt.plot(x1,y1)

plt.legend(['','y1'])

plt.show()
```

I don't want to show the first legend (I know that in this case I can just change the plot order to solve this problem)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `label` keyword and let the `legend()` function generate the labels automatically.

```
x2=[0,0.5,0.5]
y2=[0.5,0.5,0]
plt.plot(x2,y2,ls='dashed')

x1=[0,1]
y1=[0,1]
plt.plot(x1,y1, label='y1')

plt.legend()
```

Which gives you this result:

[image]